# When I tap on a image its not working properly from iphone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone-5

```
I added an image to a button. I am using gestures for animating the image in my sample app. It was working fine with iPhone 4, 4s, and 5 but the problem arise from iphone 5s.

` -(void)awakeFromNib
 {
  [super awakeFromNib];

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer =                  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(characterImagedTapped)];

 self.characterImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [self.characterImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

}

Here is the characterImagedTapped function,

' -(void) characterImagedTapped 
    { 
    if ([self.delegate      respondsToSelector:@selector(didCharacterTapped:)]) 
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didCharacterTapped:)];
    } ' this function is calling didCharacterTapped.

```
When I tapped on the button it will call didCharacterTapped function it's implementation as below:
-(void)didCharacterTapped:(BOOL)tapped    
{
    if (tapped && !isCharacterAnimating) {
        [self startWelcomeBackCharacterAnimation];
    }
}`
```

If tapped value is YES it will call startWelcomeBackCharacterAnimation. If it is NO it will skip and the image will not get animated.

Actually when I tapped on the button the tapped boolean value should be YES, but the tapped bool value always shows NO from iPhone 5s version.

Comment: -(void) characterImagedTapped
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didCharacterTapped:)])
        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didCharacterTapped:)];
}  this function is calling didCharacterTapped.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(characterImagedTapped)];self.characterImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.characterImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
} this function calls characterImagedTapped function

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Please update your question as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void) characterImagedTapped
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didCharacterTapped:)]) {
        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didCharacterTapped:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    }
    else {
        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didCharacterTapped:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
}

-(void)didCharacterTapped:(NSNumber *)tapped
{
     if (tapped.boolValue) {
    //[self startWelcomeBackCharacterAnimation];
     }
    else {
    }
}
```

You can perform the selector with object and in the selector you can access the object value as per the above code

Comment: I needs to check the tap value, if it is YES it has to get animated or it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Form your comment i can see that you are setting the `tapGestureRecognizer` to particular `imageview` i.e., `self.characterImageView`.

Try to assign it to `parentview` of the `characterImageView`.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(characterImagedTapped)];
[self.characterImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: i tried this i am getting error " Property 'view' not found on object of type JJVCCharacterView "

Comment: what is JJVCCharacterView here?

Comment: JJVCCharacterView is an implementation file where i had returned the gesture code

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(characterImagedTapped)];
   self.characterImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.characterImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}
 this code is written in JJVCCharacterView.m so i am getting error as Property 'view' not found on object of type JJVCCharacterView.

Comment: ok.. can u tell me the JJVCCharacter's subclass. Its UIViewController or NSObject

Comment: JJVCCharacterView : UIView

Comment: show me the code where you are calling the tapgesture used function

Comment: tapgesture statement is written under -(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];                                      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(characterImagedTapped)];
   self.characterImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.characterImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}